# An intuitive explanation why the Benjamini-Hochberg FDR procedure works?

Tags: intuition, false-discovery-rate, teaching

Is there a simple way of explaining why does Benjamini and Hochberg's (1995) procedure actually control the false discovery rate (FDR)? This procedure is so elegant and compact and yet the proof of why it works under independence (appearing in the appendix of their [1995 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346101?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) is not very accessible.

Comment: in my opinion, the proof of the FDR control presented here is more intuitive (note you're looking for the proof of theorem 2): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.554.9755&rep=rep1&type=pdf

There, the argument just relied on noticing that we can use the optional stopping theorem.

Comment: There's a [good lecture from Benjamini on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oONHlua2gBY) on the multiple comparisons problem, and the history and logical development of the adjustment methods used to address it.

Comment: [Ramdas et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06222) is a very nice recent paper that unifies and generalizes many multiple testing methods, and their Proposition 1(c) implies Theorem 1 in Benjamini & Hochberg (1995). The proof just applies Lemma 1(c) to bound the expectation of the FDP, and this Lemma itself is just proven by very basic multivariate calculus in their appendix.

Comment: Here's another intuitive explanation I found on StatQuest's channel on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8LQSvtjcEo

Answer (score 2):

Here is some `R`-code to generate a picture. It will show 15 simulated p-values plotted against their order. So they form an ascending point pattern. The points below the red/purple lines represent significant tests at the 0.1 or 0.2 level. The FDR ist the number of black points below the line divided by the total number of points below the line.

```
x0 <- runif(10)      #p-values of 10 true null hypotheses. They are Unif[0,1] distributed.
x1 <- rbeta(5,2,30)  # 5 false hypotheses, rather small p-values
xx <- c(x1,x0)
plot(sort(xx))
a0 <- sort(xx)
for (i in 1:length(x0)){a0[a0==x0[i]] <- NA}
points(a0,col="red")
points(c(1,15), c(1/15 * 0.1 ,0.1), type="l", col="red")
points(c(1,15), c(1/15 * 0.2 ,0.2), type="l", col="purple")
```

I hope this might give some feeling about the shape the distribution of ordered p-values has. That the lines are correct and not e.g. some parable-shaped curve, has to do with the shape of the order distributions. This has to be calculated explicitly. In fact, the line is just a conservative solution.

Comment: Would you mind adding `set.seed(<some number>)` and posting the resulting figure for people who don't read R?

Comment: None of the points fall below the line when I run this code...